# UIGestureRecognizerStateChangedv called twice when moving bezier image in a subView

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

I implemented a square draw using UIBezierPath. In order to move the same square, I implemented a UILongPressGestureRecognizer so that I can check if the square is pressed and move the square freely in the subview.

Here is some of the code:

```
square.h

...
//square coordinates and size

static const float xPoint = 10;
static const float yPoint = 16;
static const float Width = 10;
static const float Height = 20;

//bezier BitMap context
static const float contextWidht = 300;
static const float contextHeigh = 300;
... 

square.m
...
-(void)build{

  UIBezierPath *squareDraw = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(xPoint, yPoint, Width, Height)];
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(contextWidht, contextHeigh));

  // Graphic Context
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);

  [squareDraw fill];
  [squareDraw stroke];

  // Get image from Graphic Context
  UIImage *bezierImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  UIImageView *bezierImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:bezierImage];

  //subView 
  _frame = bezierImageView;
  [_frame setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

  //Gesture Recognizer
  UILongPressGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapHandler:)];
  tapGesture.delegate = (id)self;

  [_frame addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
  [self addSubview:_frame];

}

- (void)tapHandler:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *) sender{

  sender.delegate = (id)_frame;
  CGPoint touchLocation = [sender locationInView:_frame];
  CGFloat xVariation, yVariation;
  ...

  case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
    xVariation = [sender locationInView:_frame].x;
    yVariation = [sender locationInView:_frame].y;
    _frame.center = CGPointMake(xVariation, yVariation);        
  break;
  ....
}
```

Seems like, when debugging the app ( press and move the _frame ),  "UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged" is called twice and returning alternated points between the subView and some points that result from the contextWidth and contextHeight:

```
2013-07-22 14:55:00.327 bezier[10847:11603] xVariation: 22.000000
2013-07-22 14:55:00.329 bezier[10847:11603] yVariation: 28.000000
2013-07-22 14:55:00.330 bezier[10847:11603] xVariation: 150.000000 ----> ??
2013-07-22 14:55:00.330 bezier[10847:11603] yVariation: 150.000000 ----> ??
2013-07-22 14:55:00.332 bezier[10847:11603] xVariation: 29.000000
2013-07-22 14:55:00.332 bezier[10847:11603] yVariation: 28.000000
```

Why is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UILongPressGestureRecognizer always sends data continuously. If you only want one signal you need to handle this in your delegate and watch the state. From the documentation:

> Long-press gestures are continuous. The gesture begins
>   (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) when the number of allowable fingers
>   (numberOfTouchesRequired) have been pressed for the specified period
>   (minimumPressDuration) and the touches do not move beyond the
>   allowable range of movement (allowableMovement). The gesture
>   recognizer transitions to the Change state whenever a finger moves,
>   and it ends (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) when any of the fingers
>   are lifted.

Comment: The thing is that I need continuous signals and need to know at all the time the square position related to the subView. I'm not sure to understand why the UIGraphicsBeginImageContext arguments influentiate square position.

Comment: I don't think UIGraphicsBeginImageContext influences the Gesture Recognizer's positions, however, you might find out why this happens when you log out each event's view. Maybe the wierd locations happen in a totally different view and you might need to incorporate them as well into your code?